# PIL не видит FREETYPE2. ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed

Tags: python, ubuntu

Ubuntu 11.04, Python 2.7.1+, **виртуальное окружение**.

$ pip -E test install pil

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24)
              [GCC 4.5.2]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Библиотека **FreeType2** (2.4.4-1ubuntu2.1 (libfreetype6-dev)) **установлена**, но как будто её не видит.

Такой код:

```
from PIL import ImageFont

font = ImageFont.truetype("ttf/Ubuntu-I.ttf", 20)
```

Получаю ошибку:

**ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed**

Куда копать для решения вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался, но не могу закрыть свой вопрос, т.к. не хватает очков. :)

В Ubuntu 11.04 библиотеки находятся в новом месте.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
```

и переустановка PIL:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pil
```

решает проблему.

Соответственно и с другими библиотеками решение аналогичное.

Для x64 и сервера путь такой:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/